# Python3 ssl wrap_socket on a socks5 socket

Tags: ssl, socks

I am trying to establish a ssl connection using `ssl` module (for some reason I have to use this low-level method), and use `socks` module to make it go through a proxy server (e.g. `socks5h://127.0.0.1:12345` below). However, I have trouble making the request go through the proxy server.

I already have a working program that connects using `ssl` module:

```
import socket
import ssl
import socks

cli_context = ssl.create_default_context()

cli_conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
conn = cli_context.wrap_socket(cli_conn, server_hostname='bing.com')
conn.connect(('bing.com', 443))
```

However, if I change `cli_conn` to a `socks` socket, it seems that the request is actually not sent through the proxy. For example, if I capture my network traffic, I can see DNS resolution on 'bing.com'. If I remove the `wrap_socket` line and call `cli_conn.connect`, the request (correctly) goes through the proxy.

```
import socket
import ssl
import socks

cli_context = ssl.create_default_context()

cli_conn = socks.socksocket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cli_conn.set_proxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', 12345, True)
conn = cli_context.wrap_socket(cli_conn, server_hostname='bing.com')
conn.connect(('bing.com', 443))
```

Is there something wrong with my program?

Comment: I believe my proxy settings are correct. I can reproduce it by: 1. `ssh -D12345 ...`; 2. use Wireshark to look for packets with `dns.qry.name == "bing.com"`; 3. run the second program. Then I see a DNS request and response in Wireshark. (I am sure that no other programs are accessing "bing.com")

Comment: I see. It connects but not over the proxy. See the duplicate - you have to first connect the socket over the proxy and then wrap the socket.

Comment: Yes, that solves my problem. I should call `.connect` on `cli_conn` in my program, before even creating `conn`.